# How can I open a resx file in Visual Studio XML editor by default?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, ide, resources, resx

I want the 'View Code' view by default (xml editor), so that I can use features in R# File Structure window.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

1. Right Click on Resources File
2. Choose `Open With`
3. Select `XML (Text) Editor` or `XML (Text) Editor with Encoding`
4. On the right side of the dialog, click `Set as Default`

Comment: What's the difference between "XML (Text) Editor" and "XML (Text) Editor with Encoding" ?

Comment: @JohanBoule The "with encoding" one always specifically asks the encoding. The other one just autodetects it. Given the fact xml should always start with a text encoding declaration, the "with encoding" one is actually prety useless unless you're specifically dealing with noncompliant xml files that lack it.